# fill combo box in silverlight from database by coding in Service file

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have my Application in VS 2010 using Silverlight and lang C#.
My requirement is i have combo box on one of my XAML page name it as First.
I want to fill these combo box from the database,but as i cant access SQL client on XAML pages i will have to code in Service file and then use that in XAML to populate the combo box.
Can anyone provide me with code or method of how to complete this task.
Even a video tutorial will do.
Please answer at the eartliest.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "Please answer at the eartliest." Please don't use statements like this, your question has the same priority as anyone elses.

Answer (score 0):

These are a good place to start:

[How to Consume WCF and ASP.NET Web Services in Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/network-services-%28soap,-rest-and-more%29/how-to-consume-wcf-and-aspnet-web-services-in-silverlight)
[Get Started with WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services).